# How do I remove the Welcome Back at the top?

Tags: settings, games, game-center

So whenever I launch a game that uses game-center I get a message on the top of the screen that says "Welcome Back (My Game Center username)". How do I remove this? It's really annoying and it stays there for like 6 seconds. 
[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that. You could just wait till the message disappears or play in airplane mode.

Comment: @jaydm26 Yeah airplane would work, but the games I play in require Internet to play

Comment: @NetherLinks no that's for the popup I have a different issue